# building opengm with python3

Tags: python-3.x, graph-algorithm

Hi I'm trying to build [opengm](http://hci.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/opengm2/?l0=library) with python3, which is allegedly supported. Crosspost to opengm forum [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/opengm). The reason I ask is that I get an error on "PyInt_FromLong" which is [according to this article](http://python3porting.com/cextensions.html) something that shouldn't come up when porting a c library like opengm to python3. When I changed this to PyLong_FromLong, I ran into another compilation problem down the line from numpy.core.multiarray. Also note that it builds (with the appropriate ccmake options) with Python2 just fine.

My questions are:
1. Has anyone actually successfully build this?
2. Can anyone shed some light as to whether this is something on my end or theirs?

Thanks,
Chris